# How to restrict openvpn clients to communicate with other vpn clients

Tags: server, iptables, openvpn

I have this Openvpn scenario..

I have Lot of openvpn clients connected to my server, All i want is to restrict client to client communication.

for eg. i have (10.20.0.2,10.20.0.3,10.20.0.4,10.20.0.5) clients 
10.20.0.2 should not talk to 10.20.0.3 or 4, 5

Is there any way to achieve this using iptables? or through editing Configuration file?

Comment: Please check off the right answer if you have found this question to be answered.

Answer (score 4):

Stan,

gertvdijk is only partially correct.  What you must do is disable **client-to-client** in the server configuration file, but you also must configure OpenVPN in a way where every client is on their own /30 subnet, rather than having every client in the same /24 (or whatever) subnet.

So to answer your question, it is NOT possible to prevent client to client communication if they are on the same subnet using OpenVPN's server/client configuration *alone*.

With that said, of course you could use iptables to block specific traffic per host, however this would be quite cumbersome not only to configure, but also to scale.  Therefore, your best option would be to configure /30 subnets for each client.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As mentioned in the manpage:

```
   --client-to-client
          Because the OpenVPN server mode handles multiple clients  through
          a  single  tun or tap interface, it is effectively a router.  The
          --client-to-client flag tells OpenVPN to internally route client-
          to-client  traffic  rather  than  pushing  all client-originating
          traffic to the TUN/TAP interface.

          When this option is  used,  each  client  will  "see"  the  other
          clients  which  are  currently connected.  Otherwise, each client
          will only see the server.  Don't use this option if you  want  to
          firewall tunnel traffic using custom, per-client rules.
```

So, by **removing** this line from your configuration, you will restrict the clients to only talk to the server.

Comment: proto udp
dev tun
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/server.crt
key keys/server.key
dh keys/dh1024.pem
script-security 3
topology subnet
auth-user-pass-verify /etc/openvpn/auth-accept-all.sh via-env
auth-user-pass-optional
username-as-common-name

server 10.12.0.0 255.255.0.0
push "route 10.11.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0"

#client-to-client
#push "route 10.12.0.0 255.255.0.0"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 5 45
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn_status.log
verb 3
duplicate-cn
push "explicit-exit-notify 3"

Comment: @stan ? What is that comment about? If you want to supply more information for your question, please edit your question to include that.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Using openvpn 2.3.8.

Comment: @lobi Please update your question with *how* you tested it exactly (you may be confused by the /30 setup by OpenVPN), what your exact configurations are on both client and servers and what your firewall configuration looks like (of course if you allow forwarding, it will just forward by your kernel...).

Comment: client-to-client being disabled requires a /30 subnet configuration, which is not what stan brought up in his question, therefore client-to-client being disabled is not the right answer for stan.